# How can I get my app version from Play Store in React Native using Expo

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, expo

I tried to use react-native-version-checker, but I only could get user's installed version, but I also need to get the app version in play store, to compare with the installed version, to show a modal to the user asking to update the app.

As I said before, I tried to use react-native-version-checker, and I also tried some Google API, but I wasn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

1. The JSON key file can be received through the Google Cloud Console after creating a service account. The instructions provided in this link can be followed & The link to create a service account is : https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#creating-a-service-account
2. Install the googleapis package :

   ```
   npm install googleapis
   ```
3. Create a function to get the app version :

   ```
   import { google } from 'googleapis';

   const getAppVersion = async (packageName, apiKey) => {
   try {
    const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
      process.env.GOOGLE_PLAY_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      null,
      process.env.GOOGLE_PLAY_PRIVATE_KEY,
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
    );
    const androidpublisher = google.androidpublisher({ version: 'v3', auth });
    const response = await androidpublisher.edits.versions.list({
      packageName,
      editId: 'main',
    });
    const versionCode = response.data.versions[0].versionCode;
    const versionName = response.data.versions[0].versionName;
    return { versionCode, versionName };
   } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
    }
   };
   ```
4. To get the app version and compare it to the installed version, use this function:

   ```
   import { VersionCheck } from 'react-native-version-checker';

   const packageName = 'your.package.name';
   const apiKey = 'your-google-play-api-key';

   const checkAppVersion = async () => {
    const { versionCode, versionName } = await 
    getAppVersion(packageName,apiKey);
    if (versionCode && versionName) {
     const currentVersion = await VersionCheck.getVersion();
     if (currentVersion < versionCode) {
      // Show a modal to the user asking to update the app
     }
    }
   };
   ```